# Show music control after minimising application Cordova Ionic1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, background-music, background-mode

How can we force show Music-Control in notification tray when Music is playing even after minimising application. I'm using Cordova-plugin-background-mode to show notification when app is in background but it is not fulfilling my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your js file:

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
     // or
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I try this to implement but unable to achieve my required feature.